# PyCharm: Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm and I have 'Process finished with exit code 0' instead of getting (683, 11) as a result (please see attachment), could you guys help me out please? Much appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: Please add your code or output or whatever as text, in the question, not as an image with a generic description hosted on some external site.

Comment: Also, please read the help to see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Finally, "Process finished with exit code 0" is what PyCharm prints when your program finishes running with no errors. So… what do you want to change about that? Do you want to exit with an error? Or maybe you want to `print` something out before exiting with no error? Or…?

Comment: @abamert, thanks a lot for your help! It's sorted now, a silly rookie mistake:)

Comment: @abarnet is it really necessary to post three separate comments about the same thing. It is obvious he is pretty new, and still learning about PyCharm. Why not just offer some encouragement, and telling him he is doing the right thing.

Comment: @Enkouyami, what in the existing answer is missing to explain the issue?

Comment: @Enkouyami  I do not understand what you do not understand, as I mentioned it does not print unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I see why a bounty was placed on this question because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919845/pycharm-why-are-only-exit-code-lines-displayed .

Comment: Sadly this question has nothing to do with that. @Enkouyami

Comment: @Simon, good thing it gives you some upvotes :-)

Answer (score 42):

That is good news!  It means that there is no error with your code.  You have run it right through and there is nothing wrong with it. Pycharm returns 0 when it has found no errors (plus any output you give it) and returns 1 as well as an error message when it encounters errors.

Editors and scripts do not behave like the interactive terminal, when you run a function it does not automatically  show the the result. You need to actually tell it to do it yourself.

Generally you just [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) the results.

If you use `print(data.shape)` it should return what you expect with the success message `Process finished with exit code 0`.

Comment: @user9542899  No problem.  Just takes some getting used to

Comment: How do you get past the exit code? Like if I have an output dataframe that I want to access, but I can't type on a new line in the console becuase it has the exit code output.

Comment: @mikey  I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Whenever you get an exit output your script has finished executing (or there was an error and it was forced to stop).  There is no way to get around this,  a value will always be returned as soon as execution has finished.  You can use `input()` to take input, or to pause the script execution.  Otherwise it should just be a question of adding the right instructions.    If it just stops unexpectedly, then queck your code, either there is an error, or maybe a condition isn't met which causes it to just stop.

Comment: @mikey Also note that if you run it through a normal terminal (i.e. not pycharm, but through CMD or the default interpreter), execution will just stop (either the terminal will close, or you will get `>>>`,  `>` or similar to tell you it's waiting for the next command and no return value will be shown.

Comment: It would be very useful to be able to examine the variables in the code once the program has run. The exit code stops you from being able to do this. 

This is the difference between running a script and an interactive terminal. So, I think the question is how to ensure how PyCharm runs in the latter?

Answer (score 13):

`exit code 0` means you code run with no error.

Let's give a `error code` for example(clearly in the below image): in below code, the variable `lst` is an empty list, 
but we get the 5 member in it(which not exists), so the program throws `IndexError`, and `exit 1` which means there is error with the code.

[image]

You can also define exit code for analysis, for example:

```
ERROR_USERNAME, ERROR_PASSWORD, RIGHT_CODE = 683, 11, 0
right_name, right_password = 'xy', 'xy'

name, password = 'xy', 'wrong_password'

if name != right_name:
    exit(ERROR_USERNAME)

if password != right_password:
    exit(ERROR_PASSWORD)

exit(RIGHT_CODE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me when this happened was to go to

> Run --> Edit Configurations --> Execution --> check the box `Run with
>   Python Console` (which was unchecked).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to read up on`exit` codes.

`exit 0` means no error.

`exit 1` means there is some error in your code.

This is not pyCharm or python specific. This is a very common practice in most of the programming languages. Where exit 0 means the successful execution of the program and a non zero exit code indicates an error.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the program(C++/python/java..) return  0 if it runs successful.That isn't specific to pycharm or python.

In program there is no need to invoke `exit` function explicitly when it runs success it invoke exit(0) by default, invoke `exit(not_zero_num)` when runs failed.

You can also invoke `exit` function with different `code(num)` for analysis.

You can also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_(system_call) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the compilation was successful (no errors). PyCharm and command prompt (Windows OS), terminal (Ubuntu) don't work the same way. PyCharm is an editor and if you want to print something, you explicitly have to write the print statement:

```py
print(whatever_you_want_to_print)
```

In your case,

```py
print(data.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no problem in your code and you could find your print results (and other outputs) in the tab `5: Debug` rather than `4: Run`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, but couldn't even run a simple print('hello world') function.

Turns out Comodo's Firewall was stopping the script from printing. This is a pretty easy fix by deleting Python out of the Settings > Advanced > Script Analysis portion of Comodo.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with yours. And I finally solve it
I see you are trying to run code "Kaggle - BreastCancer.py"
but your pycharm try to run "Breast.py" instead of your code.
(I think Breast.py only contains functions so pycharm can run without showing any result)
Check on tab [Run] which code you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your starting the program's run from a different file than you have open there. In Run (alt+shift+F10), set the python file you would like to run or debug.