# PyCharm: Why are only exit code lines displayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

For example, running the following line of code:

```
print("Hello, world! My name is Enkouyami")
```

Only outputs this:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The only way to get it to display that text is to go to the python console.

Comment: PyCharm 2018.1.2 (Edu)
Build #PE-181.5087.43, built on May 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: thats not how it usually works ... https://i.imgur.com/VaHHquD.png

Comment: Getting it to work normally, like that @JoranBeasley, would be great.

Comment: @Enkouyami How did you setup your Pycharm?

Comment: I went to https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-edu/download/#section=windows and downloaded Pycharm Educational. Install path was set to `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 2018.1.2`; created a 64-bit launcher; installed v3.6 of python; downloaded and installed JRE x86 by JetBrains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My AV Program was pausing the installer and the Pycharm application, asking me if I want to allow the program to perform certain actions. Even though I allowed it, it messed up my Pycharm setup. Reinstalling Pycharm fixed the problem.