# Python Multiple sheet to export as csv

Tags: python, pandas

i have multiple sheets (45 + sheets) and dynamically added every week and need to export each sheet as CSV and save it in a particular location
i have used the below code to workout through python pandas

but i getting below error

```
import pandas as pd
filelocation='Z:\data\export\load_2020_08_05.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filelocation,sheet_name=None)
for key in df :
    df[key].to_csv('%s.csv' %key)
```

no error but throws below error

Process finished with exit code 0

Please advise

Thank you

Comment: this is not an error "Process finished with exit code 0". this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460212/pycharm-process-finished-with-exit-code-0/49460322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of sheet names like below:

```
import pandas as pd
xl=pd.ExcelFile(filelocation)
sheetNamesLst=xl.sheet_names
```

And loop through the sheetNamesLst

```
for sheet in sheetNamesLst:
    dfSheet = pd.read_excel(filelocation,sheet_name=sheet)
    dfSheet.to_csv(sheet+'_csvFile.csv')
```

Comment: thanks, to export i have used to_csv but dont know which location it exports the excel to csv file

Comment: the csv will land to same location where you have you python file

Comment: thanks, any idea how to change the script to export in other location

Comment: You need to change the path  dfSheet.to_csv('C:/Your/Path/Here.xlsx') Pls mark the correct answer if you think so.

Comment: i am getting this error : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:   dfSheet.to_csv('Z:\RE\drop_file\',sheet+'_csvFile.csv')

Comment: i am getting this error : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: dfSheet.to_csv('Z:\RE\drop_file\',sheet+'_csvFile.csv') –

Comment: try replacing the " \ " with " / " in your path to file.