# Discord bot won't go online

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've just started learn python and my discord bot won't go online. it just said
" Process exit with exit code 0". And there's no error with the code.

here's my code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjwHD.png)

Comment: Please add the code as a `code block` and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Add `await client.process_commands(ctx)` and `@client.event` don't need parentheses`()`. Use the code given below:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.author == client.user:
    return

  await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

Use this entire code if it still not working:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We are logged in!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author==bot.user: 
     return

   await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def ping(message) :
   await message.channel.send("Pong!!")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Thanks, But the bot still offline.

Comment: I have edited my post to entire code try this out.

Comment: It still doesn't work. There is no error in the code and after I ran the program it just said" process finished with exit code 0".

Comment: That means there is no error in code but you have to check out in settings of your IDE 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61883867/16203851

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

discord_token = "Your Token"

client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(client_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def on_ready():
  print("running")

bot.run(discord_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

### You should try this instead

```
import os
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    discord_token = "Your Token"
    
    client = discord.Client()
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="s!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("running")

bot.run(discord_token)

@bot.command()
async def on_ready():
  print("running")

bot.run(discord_token)
```

---

and the output should be   running

Answer (score -1):

The code you gave is wrong, this is correct:

```py
import os 
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") # you don't need an extra discord.client Bot is enough
token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
#you should not run the program here you should run it at last

@bot.event #no need for brackets
async def on_ready():
  print("running")

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.author == client.user:
    return

@bot.command(name="span",description="YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE") # it is command and not commands
async def span_(ctx,amount:int,*,message):
  for i in range(amount):
    await ctx.send(message)

bot.run(token) #you should run the bot now only and this will work perfectly!
```

You can find the the documentation for discord.py [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Thanks, but the bot still offline. No error found

Comment: you should have a.env file this the token or else this wont works