# Python tutorial project with kivy doesn't give the same result

Tags: python, android, kivy

I ran this code and it didn't show anything it only shows this:

> D:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/python/main.py
> Hi, PyCharm
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

```py
from kivymd.app import  MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatIconButton


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return  MDRoundFlatIconButton(icon = "language-python", pos_hint={"center_x": .5,"center_y": .5},
                                      text="halo world")

if __name__  == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Comment: maybe i did somthing wrong on the path or maybe it has to have an emulator ?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460212/pycharm-process-finished-with-exit-code-0): That is good news! It means that there is no error with your code. You have run it right through and there is nothing wrong with it. Pycharm returns 0 when it has found no errors (plus any output you give it) and returns 1 as well as an error message when it encounters errors.
~ Credits to [@Xantium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372104/xantium)

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you are? Where does the "Hi, PyCharm" in the output come from?

Answer (score 0):

Open your code in PyCharm, then press Control+Shift+F10 to run it.
You are currently running default PyCharm generated sample code.
If you want to run current Python script you have to use mentioned key combination or right click, then choose: Run 'your_script_name.py'.
After first launch, PyCharm will create launch configuration for your script, then you will be able press green Play button to run it from now. Play button runs code associated with launch configuration, not code you actually see within PyCharm editor.