# Crash course with Python

Tags: pycharm

Whenever I run a code ,

```
product = 1
for n in range(1, 10):
    product = product * n

print(product)
```

I expect a result it keeps saying "Process finished with exit code 0"

I have tried to check for any code error but i have found none in them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: Process finished with exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460212/pycharm-process-finished-with-exit-code-0)

Comment: @Sayse It's reproducible, the OC specified the Pycharm tag, not using it would mean potentially not seeing the message they mentioned. Cf my answer.

Comment: @ChrisZeThird - By cannot reproduce, I meant that there isn't enough information in the op's question to reproduce the issue, adding the code to point out that isn't any issue in the code but a problem existing outside of whats included in the post (i.e how the code is ran which would have shown there is no issue at all)

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error message, Pycharm just tells you it is done running your script, and now exit the execution with `exit code 0` (look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460212/pycharm-process-finished-with-exit-code-0)). To quote user [Xantium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49460322/19392385):

> It means that there is no error with your code. You have run it right through and there is nothing wrong with it

[image]

Comment: I didn't get the result as "362880" but rather only as "Process finished with exit code 0".

Comment: C:\Users\FRANKLIN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\FRANKLIN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py 

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: In pycharm you have at the top a drop down menu to configure run files. Make sure you selected the file with the actual code that produces a print and not an empty file. It's next to the run button